# What is "This answer has been accepted by Community on behalf of user99999999. The original asker's account is deactivated."?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I just encountered something I haven't seen before. I was looking at a poor answer that had been accepted. I hovered my mouse over the green checkmark to see when it was accepted. To my surprise, the tooltip that appeared shows the following:

> This answer has been accepted by Community on behalf of user9999999. The original asker's account is deactivated.

where an actual user id is shown instead of "user9999999". It seems the question author's account has been deleted.

The answer currently has two downvotes. Why would the "Community" accept such an answer on behalf of a deleted user? Or is this something that appears for any accepted answer when the question author's account has been deleted? (I tried to find another example of an accepted answer with a deleted question author but failed).

Though looking at the reputation history of the accepted answer's author, the answer was accepted about 5 days ago and then about 36 hours later that user lost 10 rep due to a user being removed. I have no way to know if that's actually the user that asked the associated question or not. But if so, this means the question author did accept the answer before having their account deleted. So why would the checkmark tooltip show such a message in that case? Why not simply show the normal message? For example:

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer <some date> at <some time>.

If the original question author accepts an answer before their account is deleted, why does the checkmark tooltip state that the Community user accepted the answer on their behalf? To me this implies the answer was accepted by the Community user *after* the real account was deleted. That's the confusion here. It's the misleading text of the tooltip.

Comment: Specific example would likely help (I understand not wanting to link to it and all)... but votes are sometimes transferred to the Community user if a user's profile is deleted. As such, it's not so much that the Community user accepted it, as that the Community user "owns" such votes.

Comment: @Catija It's not votes, it's the acceptance. Why would the acceptance be transferred and the tooltip text changed from the normal message? If the deleted user did actually accept the answer before their account was deleted, why can't the tooltip simply show the normal message since it was the question owner that accepted the answer?

Comment: Yea, that really needs an example... I've never seen that _"This answer has been accepted by Community on behalf..."_ message.

Comment: *"The answer currently has two downvotes. Why would the "Community" accept such an answer on behalf of a deleted user?"* Presumably the user accepted the answer prior to their account being deleted (why is unlikely to be relevant). As the user was a very active user, it appears the CM's determined that their votes (and accepts) should remain, however, as the account is to be deleted it wouldn't be able to "own" the accepts or votes any more, so they were therefore "*given*" to the Community user. I post this as a comment, as without an example I can't attempt to confirm this.

Comment: An "accept" is a kind of vote as far as the back end is concerned. We don't retain votes after account deletion often, so I honestly don't remember if we retain accepts generally or not. :D I know a lot of things but this is just one I haven't committed to memory. Essentially, @ThomA has explained the process when we delete profiles with large numbers of votes.

Comment: I guess this is normal. Example of another question from a deleted user who answered and accepted their own answer: [How can I avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or IndexOutOfBoundsException?](//stackoverflow.com/q/32568261). The tool-tip from the acceptance mark also says the above mentioned sentence. Also, yes, the user in my example was a very active user as well.

Comment: "*I tried to find another example of an accepted answer with a deleted question author but failed*" you can use [`is:q hasaccepted:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3A1) to at least filter the eligible Q&A, then find the one with the deleted account. That said, after examining this myself, l believe most (all?) acceptances are transferred to the Community user, as can be seen in the accepted answer's timeline.

Comment: @AndrewT. I had already done a search with `isaccepted=YES` to only see accepted answers but there's no easy way to then find one of those with a deleted question author.

Comment: Based on most of the comments, I've added one new paragraph at the end of my question to clarify what my actual question/issue is here. It's the misleading tooltip that appears. It leaves the wrong impression of the events that took place.

Comment: The tooltip is indeed quite misleading. No answer was every accepted by anyone than specific users (hopefully). The tooltip text should instead be changed to say that the answer was accepted by a now deleted user.

Answer (score 36):

TL;DR: This scenario occurs when a user account is deleted, however, their votes are retained, rather than deleted with their account. As such any votes (including accepts) are transferred to the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user. The Community User now *owns* their votes (including accepts); it didn't cast them.

---

Many of us are familiar with the fact that accounts on Stack Overflow can be deleted. The 2 most likely reasons are deletion due to the account breaking the CoC/ToS, and it being purged, or the owner of the account actively requesting their account being deleted. Why the user's account was deleted here is not relevant.

When a user's account is deleted, all their content remains on the site and it is owned by an anonymous account instead. Votes, however, are often removed along with the account though (especially in the event the account is being deleted due to voting fraud). This is detailed in the article [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed).

You will note, however, that this article also states the following:

> If the user has cast a large number of votes, deletion will be held up so staff may consider preserving the votes prior to the deletion. The decision is at the staff's discretion and cannot be reversed after the deletion has taken place. If you are seeing a "User was removed" event in your reputation history, it implies that the user either hadn't cast enough votes to be reviewed, or staff made the explicit decision not to preserve the votes.

This appears to be the case here. Most likely the user decided to delete their account of their own accord, but had been "law-abiding" member of the community and had made both good contributions to the site by content and votes. As a result the staff determined that it was better to retain their votes. This wouldn't cause a flood of negative reputation to a bunch of users and (in my opinion more importantly) wouldn't affect the scores of content they had voted on or accepted.

When the staff make this decision, any and all votes the user made are transferred to the owned by the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user; the votes have to have been cast by *someone* so the community user was the person the solution to that.

As a result, for accepts, a bespoke message is displayed to denote that the accept is now owned by the community user. The community user didn't *cast* the (accept) vote, the original user did, but as their account no longer exists, the community user has taken that ownership instead.

In an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32568261/2029983) shared by [Tom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426508?noredirect=1#comment973254_426508) we can actually see in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32568266/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) that the accept vote was moved; there is a comment against the accept stating:

> moved from User.Id=177800 by developer User.Id=811

<sub>User 811 on Stack Overflow is [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811), who was a long-standing Staff member and is still a semi-active community member.</sub>

Comment: While this is all good information, it doesn't answer the key part of my question - why does the green checkmark tooltip state *"This answer has been accepted by Community on behalf of user9999999."* instead of the normal message of *"The question owner accepted this as the best answer <some date> at <some time>.*"? The community user did not accept the answer, the original (but now deleted) user did. The current tooltip leaves the completely wrong impression about what happened. Yes, I understand the community user took over the account.

Comment: @HangarRash it does though? if the accept vote is owned by community... then the wording of the tooltip will be different than if it was owned by a real user.

Comment: *"why does the green checkmark tooltip state"* As stated in the TL;DR: "The Community User now owns their votes (including accepts); it didn't cast them." If that statement is unclear then I can try to reword it; can you elaborate on what about the statement you didn't understand and I'll attempt to change the wording.

Comment: *" Yes, I understand the community user took over the account."* This isn't what I state, @HangarRash , and neither is that true; the Community user does *not* take over a deleted account. The deleted user's, for example, posts are **not** owned by the community user. This can be clearly seen in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32568261/2029983) shared by [Tom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) in their [comment](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426508?noredirect=1#comment973254_426508); the post is owned by the anonymous user "user177800".

Comment: Perhaps an analogy would help you understand better, @HangarRash . For example,  a family member purchased a luxury car; they own said car. This family member then passed away, and in their Will they leave the car to you, meaning you now *own* the car, however, you did not *purchase* said car; the family member did. The same is true here; the Community user owns the car (vote), but they didn't purchase (cast) the car (vote). The message is letting you know that though the community user owns the vote, they didn't cast it.

Comment: @ThomA I just added a new paragraph at the end of my question to clarify what my question is trying to focus on. When I read "*This answer has been accepted by Community on behalf of user9999999"* this tells me that the Community user accepted the answer *after* the original account was deleted. And in the specific case I was looking at, that was doubly confusing because it's a poor answer. So yes, the tooltip text needs to be made less confusing somehow. I don't understand why the tooltip needs to be different at all. The standard message still applies.

Comment: My answer still applies @HangarRash ; I actually don't see anything to add (apart from the analogy if that helps clarify for you).

Comment: @ThomA A car analogy? Is this Slashdot? :) Seriously though, I don't agree at all. The current tooltip leaves the wrong impression of the events that took place. The Community user did *not* accept the answer on behalf of user9999999. user999999 accepted the answer. It's just plain confusing.

Comment: It seems like, @HangarRash , you don't want to know *what* the wording means and *why* would the accept be by the community user, which is what the question you've written asks, but want to know *why* that wording was chosen. That isn't what you ask here in my opinion, and changing your question now would invalidate my answer and many of the comments; which is frowned against.

Comment: @ThomA How does one access that timeline screen while viewing a question? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Click the [clock (like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgEvu.png) icon next to the post, @HangarRash .

Comment: @ThomA I am happy to learn what the wording means. But my question has always been why it says what is says and the fact that it is misleading and confusing. Because again, the Community user did not accept the answer, the original user accepted the answer. Just because the account was deleted and the Community account took it over, does not mean that the Community user accepted the answer. I've already stated several times why the current message makes no sense. Explaining how the whole process works doesn't change the fact that the message is misleading.

Comment: *"But my question has always been why it says what is says"* The title of the question disagrees with that. Why and *what* are quite different: *"What is "This answer has been accepted by Community on behalf of user99999999. The original asker's account is deactivated."?"*

Comment: @ThomA But the question is the question. The title is not the question. Yes, in hindsight, a slightly different title may have been better. But read the actual question. My question asks "why?" several times. As a contributor to SO, I always base my answers on the actual question, not the title. It's the question that has all of the information. A title is just an attempt to summarize the entire question into one line. And rarely is that done perfectly.

Comment: @HangarRash hopefully "As a contributor to SO" you also aware that sometimes the way the author reads their own question is different from how everyone else read it and a better approach is to ask a separate new question compred to arguing along the lines of "every reader of the question is complete #$$%#" (or whatever your favorite curse is). In particular you seem to be looking for Feature-Request to update that tooltip to something else.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, there is a natural follow-on question/request to get the tooltip changed. I agree that that is a separate request from my current question of why things are as they are.

Comment: _The Community User now owns their votes (including accepts); it didn't cast them_ I agree with @HangarRash that the current wording of the tooltip strongly suggests (i.e., means) that the Community User _did_ cast the accept vote, so the tooltip is incorrect, or misleading at best.

Comment: I totally agree with the OP on the impression of what the message means. In the situation where the community user took over the accept vote, I don't think a special message is needed if the question still shows the original user's name. OTOH, if the _question_ is now owned by the community member, then the accept message should read something like "<original owner> accepted this as the best answer <some date and time>. That account has since been deleted."

Comment: @ThomA - thanks for explaining. I also think the tooltip wording is wrong. The tooltip is very clear, it says "*answer has been accepted by **Community**...*".  That's simply not true. And the "owner of the acceptance vote" is pretty much not something that's at all relevant as far as I can see. Default tooltip text would be fine.

Comment: Whether the 'community' owns the votes of deleted users is an implementation detail, which I, as a user, don't care about. Having a customized tooltip for this case doesn't give me any new information (I can already see that the user is deleted from the user card on the question).